# Alternative for jQuery scroll function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scroll, scrolltop

I've got a jQuery script as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#algemeen').css('position','fixed');
        $('#algemeen').animate({
            top: '0px',
            left: '70%',
            width: '10%'
        }, 200);
    } else {
        $('#algemeen').css('position','absolute');
        $('#algemeen').animate({
            top: '300px',
            left: '100px',
            width: '200px'
        }, 200);
    }
});

});
```

As you can see, I've got this div '#algemeen' that changes its position when the page is scrolled 100px down. The problem is, it's very laggy and it often stays in its 'downscroll' position when I've scrolled up. Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try without the animate , i.e. `$('#algemeen').css({top: '300px', left: '100px', width: '200px'});` you are animating for 200ms on every scroll (as you are always matching one of those two conditions). Also, do your styling in css and have the jquery simply add and remove a class (isScrolled etc), that will also improve the perf as the js is doing much less work and css is doing what it's best at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way is to use [CSS transition property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) and jQuery to [add](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)/[remove](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) class. Please check **[this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d22cz8p9/)**, we toggle class `animated`:

**Javascript**:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    var scroller = $('#algemeen');
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            scroller.addClass('animated');
        } else {
            scroller.removeClass('animated');
        }
    });
});
```

Than **CSS**:

```
#algemeen {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    transition: all linear .2s;
}
#algemeen.animated {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 70%;
    width: 10%;
}
```

It is better because:

- browser animations are faster than script, they use less CPU, they are better optimized and because of that they often look better
- it is easier to change CSS than script, you can apply media queries etc.

[This article](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/jquery-vs-css3-transitions/) may convince you (has a nice demo).

Answer (score 0):

Something I like to do is have an event listen for any time you scroll, and when `window.scrollY` gets to the desired point, then I run animations/functions/whatever. 
I might also add in a boolean or int value that changes when you apply the change so that you are not constantly making the change every time the if or else statement passes. (may be why it is lagging for you)

```
var changesMade = 0;

window.onscroll = function() {
    if (window.scrollY > 100 && changesMade != 1) {
        $('#algemeen').css('position','fixed');
        $('#algemeen').animate({
            top: '0px',
            left: '70%',
            width: '10%'
        }, 200);
        changesMade = 1;
    } else if (window.scrollY < 100 && changesMade != 0) {
        $('#algemeen').css('position','absolute');
        $('#algemeen').animate({
            top: '300px',
            left: '100px',
            width: '200px'
        }, 200);
        changesMade = 0;
    }
}
```

Hope this is helpful.